# Sump pump running every 20 seconds, sometimes constantly

Tags: pump, sump

I live in a lower spot with a high water table. We still have snow on the ground and we are getting some rain. I've had two occasions in the past couple of weeks where water entering the pit has been faster than the water being pumped out.  I have a 1/2 HP Wayne (CDU800) and a battery backup. My pump had to run four about 7-8 hours straight before it finally caught up and was able to shut off for a few seconds. Today the pump is running about every 20 seconds or so. I do have a couple of downspouts that go into the ground, but I have diverted them to go out on top of the ground as the pipe in the ground appears to be frozen. Half of my house is surrounded by a wrap around porch, so there isn't even that much snow / water near the house. Also, the single discharge line (1 1/2 ") is pumped up about 10 feet and then goes 30-40' away from house into a ditch. I can confirm that I have no issues with discharge line or check valve. I also have the pumps sitting on a brick to raise it a bit, but the weepers do not fill up before the pit is discharged...unless of course the water is coming in at a crazy rate.

I'm looking for some recommendations on how to improve this situation. I was wondering about getting a 3/4 or 1 HP pump, but I fear this would fail quickly with too many short cycles. Maybe I put in a 2" discharge line? At the very least I'm thinking about just have a 3/4 or 1 HP on standby, that I can quickly install in the pit when I need it. Seems like a waste, but not sure what else to do.

Appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Comment: You don't state that it's overflowing, so other than not building your house where it's built, you seem to have it covered with the present pump. If terrain allows (probably not) some French drains to remove water from the area of the house would be good. If terrain does not allow, well, you need a pump, you have a pump, and that's how water works... You could also add a second pump of the same size with a pump control box to alternate pumps normally and run both if too high, rather than a single larger pump.

Comment: Also live in a high water table and in a low spot with, mine is running every 46 seconds, but when it does run, it only runs 6 seconds. There is a constant large water flow, so has me thinking: is it that you pump cannot empty efficiently?  Calc the water in rate and use large enough pump to handle that rate. Would also try and understand why water flow is so high. If the pump is bad, perhaps it is on but not evicting much water, so runs longer, and loses the battle against the water

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem. If the pump is running every 20 seconds, that implies that water ingress is taking the sump from "empty cutoff" to "full cutoff" *in 20 seconds*.

That means in 40 seconds it will have overflowed the sump, and in 5 minutes your basement will have an inch of water in it.  In the 2 hours your new pump takes to install, you'll be treading water to finish the install.

*Is your water ingress really that bad?*

Becuase if it's not, then what's really happening is the water being ejected by the sump pump is landing back in the sump the moment the motor cuts out.  Maybe a broken pipe  just outside which is causing the water to fall back in, or a broken check valve - is the output of the pipe submerged in water? Because water might be syphoning back in.

Or for that matter if the pipe is broken below the level of water pooling around your house, it will simply allow water into your sump.

Thoroughly inspect your output piping to make sure nothing is awry.  If water ingress is that bad, the advice of multiple sump pumps is the best I've heard, but really, you'd best move everything out of that basement, because your first power outage is going to turn it into a swimming pool and everything down there will be ruined.

Also make sure your roof drains are sensibly designed - allowing water to accumulate or pool anywhere near the foundation is asking for disaster.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My water alarm rose again this evening, within 1 inch for the top of the pit. Both primary pump and battery were running non-stop and still the water was rising. I decided to take both out and throw in a 1HP pump. It is slowly draining the pit, but its been running non-stop as well for about 15 minutes now.

Comment: The drainage line runs out under my porch and gravity takes it down towards a ditch which is quite far away. Yes the ditch is full of water, but i'm not sure how it could come back in. I've lived in this house for 6 years now and this is the first time i've had this problem. It's strange because we actually have less snow this year.

Comment: The amount of water entering the pit from the weeper and another solid pipe is crazy. I can't even seem to empty those pipes if I make the pump run longer.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure what you mean by "not sure how it could come in", please make sure you're familiar with what a syphon is, because if the outlet is underwater and the top of that water is higher than the sump, that explains everything.

Comment: @Mike are you saying the water comes out under your porch?  Or are you just saying the pipe exits the house under your porch and the pipe goes to the ditch?

Answer (score 0):

This happened in two nearby towns.. the water utility had stopped pumping ground water and this caused basements to take on water.

My neighbor's pump runs frequently and she has a deep sump. When I put my sump in I used a 5 gal joint compound bucket as a concrete form and do not have a problem. Thus my sump is very shallow and I do not have this problem. There is an underground stream running down the street. I know the stream is there because I saw it when they they excavated for a church half a block away. So you may want to compare your sump depth to that of your neighbors.

Another possible source is water traveling in gravel placed under any pipes running down your street.

Answer (score -1):

A friend had a basement in an area with high water table. He went with several ordinary size ( 1/3 Hp ?) pumps. It apparently worked well. Three pumps in the sump; one ran most of the time . Number 2 came on if it had recently rained. Number 3 came on if it was raining.  Each had its own pipe out to the ditch. He kept a new spare pump. I am not suggesting you do it, but he had rigged a power supply around the electric meter because it used so much power. ( I am sure he moved years ago).

Comment: Yeah I don't know if I could fit 3, (18" diamter pit), but my 1hp pump at a higher level may work.